# How to achieve slide in and out animation in android compose between two Views Synchronized

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I know I can use the `AnimatedVisibility` Composable function and achieve slide-in animation for the visibility animation, but what I want to achieve is when one layout is in entering animation the other in the exit animation, something similar to the image below.

**NB** : I know that I should use Navigation compose for different screens and that animation between destinations is still under development, but I want to achieve this on the content of a part of screen, similar to CrossFade Animation.

[image]

Comment: You should give [Navigator Compose](https://github.com/KaustubhPatange/navigator/tree/master/navigator-compose) a try. It provides some built-in `enter` & `exit` animations when navigating to other destinations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After digging in the code of CrossFade I implemented a similar one for the cross slide and it enables reverse animation for when pressing backButton

Here it is : https://gist.github.com/DavidIbrahim/5f4c0387b571f657f4de976822c2a225

**Usage Example**

```
@Composable
fun CrossSlideExample(){
    var currentPage by remember { mutableStateOf("A") }
    CrossSlide(targetState = currentPage, reverseAnimation: Boolean = false) { screen ->
        when (screen) {
            "A" -> Text("Page A")
            "B" -> Text("Page B")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

As you mentioned, this animation should be implemented by the Navigation Library and there's [a ticket opened to that](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172112072).

Having that in mind, I'm leaving my answer here and I hope it helps...

I'll break it in three parts:

1. The container:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun SlideInAnimationScreen() {
    // I'm using the same duration for all animations. 
    val animationTime = 300 

    // This state is controlling if the second screen is being displayed or not
    var showScreen2 by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    // This is just to give that dark effect when the first screen is closed...
    val color = animateColorAsState(
        targetValue = if (showScreen2) Color.DarkGray else Color.Red,
        animationSpec = tween(
            durationMillis = animationTime,
            easing = LinearEasing
        )
    )
    Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
       // Both Screen1 and Screen2 are declared here...
    }
}
```

2. The first screen just do a small slide to create that parallax effect. I'm also changing the background color from Red to Dark just to give this overlap/hide/dark effect.

```kotlin
// Screen 1
AnimatedVisibility(
    !showScreen2,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    enter = slideInHorizontally(
        initialOffsetX = { -300 }, // small slide 300px
        animationSpec = tween(
            durationMillis = animationTime, 
            easing = LinearEasing // interpolator
        )
    ),
    exit = slideOutHorizontally(
        targetOffsetX = { -300 }, =
        animationSpec = tween(
            durationMillis = animationTime, 
            easing = LinearEasing
        )
    )
) {
    Box(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(color.value) // animating the color
    ) {
        Button(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center),
            onClick = {
                showScreen2 = true
            }) {
            Text(text = "Ok")
        }
    }
}
```

3. The second is really sliding from the edges.

```
// Screen 2
AnimatedVisibility(
    showScreen2,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    enter = slideInHorizontally(
        initialOffsetX = { it }, // it == fullWidth
        animationSpec = tween(
            durationMillis = animationTime, 
            easing = LinearEasing
        )
    ),
    exit = slideOutHorizontally(
        targetOffsetX = { it },
        animationSpec = tween(
            durationMillis = animationTime, 
            easing = LinearEasing
        )
    )
) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Blue)
    ) {
        Button(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center),
            onClick = {
                showScreen2 = false
            }) {
            Text(text = "Back")
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: can we refactor your solution to a more generic one that supports  multiple screens, similar to CrossFade?

Answer (score 3):

Now we have an official solution for this. Lately [Google Accompanist](https://github.com/google/accompanist) has added a library which provides Compose Animation support for Jetpack Navigation Compose..

https://github.com/google/accompanist/tree/main/navigation-animation

Comment: Ironically, but, Google Accompanist does not allow exact this type of an animation.

Comment: Has anyone figured out how to achieve this animation using the Accompanist libraries?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an integrated solution based on @nglauber solution giving the illusion of View Sliding INDEPENDENTLY OF VIEW BACKGROUND.

[image: View Sliding]

Demo Part — — —

```
@Composable
fun ViewSliderDemo() {
    val slider = ViewSlider()

    Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        slider.View(
            type= ViewSlider.Type.parent,
        ) {
            Button(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center),
                onClick = {
                    slider.state.value = true
                }) {
                Text(text = "Child >>>>")
            }
        }
        slider.View(
            type= ViewSlider.Type.child,
        ) {
            Button(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center),
                onClick = {
                    slider.state.value = false
                }) {
                Text(text = "<<<< Parent")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Code part — — —

```
class Observed<T>(startWith: T) : MutableState<T> {
    private var _value by mutableStateOf(startWith)
    override var value: T = startWith
        get() = _value
        set(value) {
            _value = value
            field = value
        }
    override fun component1(): T = value
    override fun component2(): (T) -> Unit = { value = it }
}

class ViewSlider {
    val animationTime = 300
    var state = Observed(startWith = false)

    enum class Type { parent, child }

    @OptIn(ExperimentalAnimationApi::class)
    @Composable
    fun View(
        type: Type,
        content: @Composable () -> Unit
    ) {
        var shadowSize by remember { mutableStateOf( 10.dp ) }
        AnimatedVisibility(
            visible = if (type == Type.parent) !state.value else state.value,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            enter = slideInHorizontally(
                initialOffsetX = {
                    if (type == Type.parent) -300 else it
                },
                animationSpec = tween(
                    durationMillis = animationTime,
                    easing = LinearEasing // interpolator
                )
            ),
            exit = slideOutHorizontally(
                targetOffsetX = {
                    if (type == Type.parent) -300 else it
                },
                animationSpec = tween(
                    durationMillis = animationTime,
                    easing = LinearEasing
                )
            )
        ) {
            shadowSize = if (this.transition.currentState == this.transition.targetState) 0.dp else 10.dp
            Box {
                if (type == Type.child) {
                    Row {
                        Box(Modifier
                                .fillMaxHeight()
                                .width(shadowSize)
                                .background(
                                    brush = Brush.horizontalGradient(
                                        colors = listOf(Color.LightGray, Color.Gray)
                                    )
                                )
                        )
                        Spacer(Modifier.weight(1f))
                    }
                }
                content()
                if (type == Type.parent) {
                    Row {
                        Spacer(Modifier.weight(1f))
                        Box(Modifier
                                .fillMaxHeight()
                                .width(shadowSize)
                                .background(
                                    brush = Brush.horizontalGradient(
                                        colors = listOf(Color.Gray, Color.LightGray)
                                    )
                                )
                        )
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -7):

As of now, we don't have anything comparable to `Activity` Transitions in Compose.
Jetpack should be working on them I hope. An awful lot of transition APIs are either `internal` or `private` to Compose Library so implementing a fine one is harder.

If for production, Kindly use `Activity/Fragment` with Navigation Host. If not use `AnimatedVisibility` to slide without the navigation component.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172112072